# JSoup Grabbing HTML value returns null?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to use the Jsoup java library to pull a random word from an online random word generator. Here is my code, the link to the random word generator is in there:

```
public class getWord {

    public static void grabWord(){

Document doc = Jsoup.parse( "UTF-8", "http://watchout4snakes.com/CreativityTools/RandomWord/RandomWord.aspx");

Elements links = doc.getElementsByClass("randomWord");
 String linkText = links.text();
System.out.println(linkText);
}
}
```

If you go into the random word generator link and view the source, there is this  that contains the random word:

```
<span id="tmpl_main_lblWord" class="randomWord">indictment</span>
```

As you can see, the class is random word, I am trying to use the getElementsByClass method to get that element, as it is the only element on the page with the class of randomWord. I have also tried using `doc.select("span[class$=randomWord]")` That yielded the same result, nothing printing. Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: @infgeoax How would I do that?

Comment: @infgeoax And there would only be one return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the [parse](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method that accepts HTML content. You need to use the one takes a `URL` instead. Replace

```
Jsoup.parse("UTF-8", "http://watchout4snakes.com/CreativityTools/RandomWord/RandomWord.aspx");
```

with

```
Jsoup.parse(new URL("http://watchout4snakes.com/CreativityTools/RandomWord/RandomWord.aspx"), 4000);
```

More convenient is:

```
Jsoup.connect("http://watchout4snakes.com/CreativityTools/RandomWord/RandomWord.aspx").get();
```

Comment: Thankyou :) that worked. The first random word it just made for me was error so I got a little confused xD.